# Trouble undestanding regular expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, regular-expressions

I am reading a book example on regular expressions and I have a trouble to get why the asnwer is correct.

"Write a regular expression for the regular language that contains all the strings by 0's and 1's , in which the digits next to 1's , are always 0's"

So , basically , we just need to create a regular expression , that "abandons" '11's (two 1's net to each other)
THe answer in the book is:
$(\epsilon|1)((101)^*|0)^*(1|\epsilon)$

after the suggestion of an aswer below we could simply write:
$((\epsilon|1)((101)^*|0)^*$

I don't get it.
$((101)^* | 0)^*$ can create a term $(101)(101)$ which is forbidden , can't it??
or maybe we have $1(101)$ by this regular expression, can't we?

I am thinking it should be something like:

$(1|\epsilon)((01)^*|0)^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left((101)^*\mid 0\right)^*$ cannot create $(101)(101)$, since it cannot create any parentheses, but it **can** create $101101$ and $1101$, which, as you say, are not in the language. Your suggestion of $(\epsilon\mid 10)(1\mid\epsilon)\left((01)^*\mid 0\right)^*(01\mid\epsilon)$ works but is more complicated than necessary: $(\epsilon\mid 1)\left(01\mid 0\right)^*$ does the job.

Comment: @yes, I added the parantheses just to make it clearer , that's what I meant.

Comment: @brucebanner: I thought that you probably knew that, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: @yes you did the right thing. thank you for your answer!

Comment: @brucebanner: You’re welcome!